# POSTMAN - Save a property value from a JSON response

Tags: json, postman

I am new to both JSON and Postman(as of yesterday).

I'm trying to do something very simple, I've created a GET request which pulls in a list of forms in a JSON response. I want to take this response and get the first "id" token and place it in a variable.

I am using a global variable but would like to use a collection variable if possible. Either way here is what I am doing.

I've tried several things, most recently this:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setGlobalVariable("id", jsonData.args.id);
```

As well as this:

```
pm.test("GetId", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.globals.set("id", jsonData.id);    
});
```

Response code looks like this:

```
{
   "forms":[
      {
         "id":"3197239",
         "created":"2018-09-18 11:37:39",
         "db":"1",
         "deleted":"0",
         "folder":"151801",
         "language":"en",
         "name":"Contact Us",
         "num_columns":"2",
         "submissions":"0",
         "submissions_unread":"0",
         "updated":"2018-09-18 12:02:13",
         "viewkey":"xxxxxx",
         "views":"1",
         "submissions_today":0,
         "url":"https://xxx",
         "data_url":"",
         "summary_url":"",
         "rss_url":"",
         "encrypted":false,
         "thumbnail_url":null,
         "submit_button_title":"Submit Form",
         "inactive":false,
         "timezone":"US/Eastern",
         "permissions":150
      },
      {
         "id":"3197245",
         "created":"2018-09-18 11:42:02",
         "db":"1",
         "deleted":"0",
         "folder":"151801",
         "language":"en",
         "name":"Football Draft",
         "num_columns":"1",
         "submissions":"0",
         "submissions_unread":"0",
         "updated":"2018-09-18 12:11:54",
         "viewkey":"xxxxxx",
         "views":"1",
         "submissions_today":0,
         "url":"https://xxxxxxxxx",
         "data_url":"",
         "summary_url":"",
         "rss_url":"",
         "encrypted":false,
         "thumbnail_url":null,
         "submit_button_title":"Submit Form",
         "inactive":false,
         "timezone":"US/Eastern",
         "permissions":150
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This would get the first `id`:

```
pm.globals.set('firstId', _.first(pm.response.json().forms).id)
```

That would get the first in the array each time so it would set a different variable it that response changed.

---

The `test` that you created was nearly there but the reference needed to go down a level into the `forms` array:

```
pm.test("GetId", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json()
    pm.expect(jsonData.forms[0].id).to.equal("3197239")
    pm.globals.set("id", jsonData.forms[0].id)   
})
```

The `[0]`is referencing the first id in the first object within the array. For example `[1]` would get the second one and so on.

---

You currently cannot set a collection level variable using the `pm.*` API - These can only be added manually and referenced using the `pm.variables.get('var_name')` syntax.

**Edit:**

In the new versions of the desktop app you can set variables at the Collection level using `pm.collectionVariables.set()`.

Comment: thank you that worked! I was so close! Much appreciated.

Comment: No worries - Do you want to accept that as an answer for this question.

Comment: "pm.collectionVariables.set" is available now to set collection variables. Also, @DanaFisher you should accept Danny's answer so he gets credit for it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the name or any other attribute if you want to set the id as a global variable then this is the way.

```
for(var i=0; i<jsonData.forms.length; i++)
{
    if (jsonData.forms[i].name==="Contact Us")
    {
       pm.environment.set("id", jsonData.forms[i].id);
    }   

}
```